# my EC2 instance seems down and it won't reboot from the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running on Ubuntu 14.04 that's been up for about 3 months. I got its IP address whitelisted from my payment processing partner so it's kind of a hard decision to reboot it since its IP address is going to change. But here's what has happened now : I was working on it via ssh, launching a node.js process and watching the logs as I was using a mobile app communicating with it, then all of a sudden it stopped responding to keyboard input. Now I can't visit any website hosted on it and I can't ssh in :

```
ssh: connect to host ***.***.***.*** port 22: Can't assign requested address
```

And I can't even reboot the instance from the console : I click reboot, I get the alert dialog I click "Yes I am sure", nothing happens, the instance is still running after refreshing the page and with the same IP address.

What should I do ?

Comment: You need to assign an elastic IP so that it will stay the same. Not that it solves your immediate problem. I would contact AWS on this one and just have them restart things from their end.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [sf] or [su].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes EC2s crash and can take hours to respond to a reboot from the console. In rare cases Amazon has to be involved to kill it. Best thing to do is take a snapshot of your attached storage and create a new EC2 instance.

With regards to your IP you should be using an Elastic IP. You get one free one per EC2 and it's yours to keep till you release it. If you have one you can recreate an EC2 from snapshots and then attach your Elastic IP and be up and running in minutes.

**EDIT**

As an example my EC2 crashed around 2 months ago with your same problem. I recreated everything from snapshots and moved my Elastic IP. After about 4-6 hours the EC2 finally stopped and I could start it again but I have read in forums that occasionally AWS needs to get involved.

Comment: I can have a free elastic IP even if I only got my instance from a free tier account ?

Comment: Yes, the free tier includes it as long as it's attached to a running EC2.

Comment: Thanks ! One last thing : do you have any idea what could have caused this issue ? I had an OpenVPN daemon running only accepting connection from 3 clients (me and 2 friends) I thought it might be it or maybe certbot did something nasty although they seem trusty

Comment: No, mine had been running for around a 2 months with nothing changing on it. I would say AWS's software had an error. It's best to build redundancy into your architecture (free tier also gives you a load balancer, though only once EC2). It's really designed for throw away appliances.

Comment: Something weird just happened : I've just noticed that I could still run the mobile app. Actually i can even browse the websites and ssh in from my phone (with termux). So it seems that it's only from my computer that I can't reach my server anymore neither via ssh nor web browser. That same computer that spent the whole day ssh'd on the server. I am super confused because right when this happened, I couldn't reboot the instance so I figured it was stuck or something...

Comment: Running something like Fail2Ban thats preventing you on your IP? It could have crashed, finally rebooted and then a firewall or something is preventing you from connecting.

Comment: Nothing like that :/ plus my computer and my phone were under the same Wi-Fi so both would have been Fail2Banned

Comment: I can confirm that a reboot might take a while to go through. I had an EC2 instance that was no longer working properly (but still marked healthy), and it took ~20 minutes to respond to my repeated Reboot attempts.